# How can I read the message I send with the pickle.dump method in C # as a string?

Tags: python, c#, socketserver

I have socket server between python and C#. (Python server - C# client) I want to send nested array to C# client with pickle.dump from python server. But when I try to read message with C# client I get a meaningless string. It like "?]q(]q(KKKKe]q(Kee."
I actually want to send nested array like [[1,2,3,4],[10,11,12,13]] and read like that. How can I do that ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should probably use JSON or some other common serialization format when sending messages from one technology to another. I've never used pickle, but from the docs, it looks like it's pretty specific to Python.

Comment: Thank you. Seems logical. But I used json a long time ago. Can I dynamically add data to json and send it to the client continuously ?

Comment: You can keep re-serializing and sending that. I'm not sure what you mean by continuously - I'd probably have to see some example code.

Comment: I solved the problem Collen. I used json.dumps(dictionary).encode('utf-8') in python and read data from C# client. Thx for your help.

Comment: Nice work! Glad I could help steer you in the right direction.